# .csproj files and SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, tortoisesvn

Good day!

I'm using SVN for years (both command-line and not integrated in VS studio clients like TortoiseSVN) and *VS Express*. Most of my project used "Web Site" project type in the past. When ASP.NET MVC came I stick to solution and projects for ASP.NET MVC sites (as default ASP.NET MVC application template).

The problem is when someone add\moves files in different parts of the project the file structure maintained by SVN is completely ok. But changes in project structure for sure give SVN conflict in `.csproj` files. So we need to re-add files to the project, or edit `csproj` by hand.

Are there any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use the integrated plugin: [Ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/). It should manage the SVN changes for you if you make the changes directly in VS.